# JPA - How to update child object in OneToMany relationship?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have a Customer class where each customer can have multiple Products. The class is as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Product.class, mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

//getters and setters here

}
```

and the Product class holds OneToOne relation with other Classes and it is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")

public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Customer.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Customer customer;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonManagedReference
private SomeType1 someType1;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonManagedReference
private SomeType2 someType2;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonManagedReference
private SomeType3 someType3;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonManagedReference
private SomeType4 someType4;


//getters and setters here

    }
```

I am trying to achieve following functionality with this:

Given Customer ID and Product ID, update the values in `SomeType1, SomeType2, SomeType3` classes. I am getting the updated `SomeType1, SomeType2, SomeType3` objects from UI and I want to update the values in DB. I already have `PUT` method in place for this.

Here's the `PUT` method:

```
@PutMapping(value = "customer/{id}/product/{product_id}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@PathVariable final String id, 
        @PathVariable final String product_id, @RequestBody final Product product) {
    Optional<Customer> customerInDb = customerService.getCustomerById(id);
    if (!customerInDb.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                MessageFormat.format("Customer with id {0} does not exist.", id));
    } else {
        product.setId(Long.valueOf(product_id));
        product.setCustomer(customerInDb.get());
        Product savedProduct = customerService.createProduct(product);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedProduct);
    }
}
```

I am getting following error for this REST call:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.myapp.arg.entities.SomeType2#12]
```

What could be the reason for this?

createProduct method:

```
@Override
public Product createProduct(Product product) {
    Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(product);
    return savedProduct;
}
```

JSON input to the `PUT` method:

```
{
   "id":9,
   "someType1":{
      "id":9,
      "avg":20,
      "total":20
   },
   "someType2":{
      "id":9,
      "circum":45.0,
      "strength":45.0,
      "totalNav":0.0
   },
   "someType3":{
      "id":9,
      "tensile":87,
      "pull":128,
      "push":56,
      "upward":28.0
   },
   "measuredBy":"SJ",
   "addedDate":"2021-05-23",
   "type":"Prime"
}
```

Comment: please show `createProduct` method. And in the future dont abstract the problem with someType1, someType2 - that makes it harder for us to follow/solve

Comment: @JAsgarov I have added the `createProduct` method in the question. Thank you for the suggestion regarding abstracting the problem.

Comment: 1. what do you pass as a `@RequestBody final Product product`? share a json plz, especially `SomeTypeN` properties

2. it's totally bad idea to pass entity as a model, you should use separate classes for transport and persisten goals

3. show `Customer` mapping in the `Product`

4. what does `product(Long.valueOf(product_id))`  do? is it some method or missprint?

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov I have updated the question with your suggestions. Thank you for your feedback (point 2 in your comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the same id for all of your entities. ID must be unique

Comment: But these IDs are automatically generated for the child entities. The ID generation strategy for these child entities is set to `GenerationType.AUTO`. Do I need to change this? Since the child entities have different tables, it is possible that the IDs might be same.

Comment: you can keep AutoGeneration, just remove this line         `product.setId(Long.valueOf(product_id));` so that jpa can take care of generating aids automatically